# Why isn't Excel recognizing the apostrophe as a special character and disappearing?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm prepping sheets in Excel using Python Pandas and I am trying to keep the text from reformatting to date.  In this example, the 05-Nov ['05-Nov] is the fiscal month(05) of November and not the day. When I open the Excel sheet the apostrophe is not disappearing unless I click inside the formula bar and hit enter.  The only reason I care is because the apostrophe is transferring to my pivot tables and not being recognized as a special character there either.

[image: Excel Picture]

Comment: What is the format of the cells in that column?

Comment: If the cells are formatted as Text instead of General then what is in them is treated as a literal string  - even if it starts wit han apostrophe of equals sign.

Comment: I replaced with ctrl+r ' with ' and that seemed to do the trick.